# Wordpress: get posts and show 50 first characters

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show the three latest posts with the 50 first characters. And a "read more" link at the end. Like this:

> #### My first post
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipiscing elit. Aenean vulputate. Read more...
>
> #### My second post
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipiscing elit. Aenean vulputate. Read more...
>
> #### My third post
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipiscing elit. Aenean vulputate. Read more...

Do I use get_posts? How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This became my solution:**

In the template:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
?> 

<h2 class="news"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In functions.php:

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
       global $post;
    return '... <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read more</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');


function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this without the going to functions.php page.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 1 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php the_content_rss('', TRUE, '', 33); ?> <a class="continue" href="<?php     the_permalink() ?>">Continue Reading &raquo;</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Good insight about using `the_content_rss()` as it offers a nice way to limit character length without all the shenanigans of these other approaches.

Comment: `the_content_rss()` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you use get_posts:

```
$options = array(
    'number_of_posts' => 3
);

$myposts = get_posts($options);
foreach( $myposts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    echo '<h2>' . the_title . '</h2>';
    echo the_content();
}
```

You could use something like "$mycontent = get_the_content()" and then manipulate it with phps substring, but honestly: DO NOT DO IT!

For your read more function Wordpress has the perfectly fine more tag in the editor, which will automagically work for you, if you try something like this:

```
foreach( $myposts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    echo '<h2>' . the_title . '</h2>';
    echo the_excerpt();
    echo '<a href="' . the_permalink() . '">More &raquo;</a>';
}
```